# Is there a way to connect QTP to MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, backend, qtp, hp-uft

I am creating a backend using QTP and need it to connect to mongoDB to populate the internal QTP DataTable.

Have you ever seen this been done and/or do you have any suggestions on how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Currently I have a couple of ideas:

- Create a Java application that mirrors the mongodb collection using a JTable. QTP would then read the JTable and populate its own DataTable.
- Run some QTP cmd shell or a Batch (.bat) script that through the command-prompt connects to mongodb and reads the collection. QTP would then read the output of the shell and populate its DataTable.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: what qtp version do you use? Can you upgrade to latest UFT Version?